# Unable to send characters after null from a file to the server in c

Tags: c, string, data-structures

OS: Ubuntu(20.04)
MCU: ESP WROOM 32
Coding language: C

I have a file of 120KB with lot of null characters in between. For example:

```c
char[50] = "welcome\0  my name\0 is";
```

is my string, I am trying to send entire text(including \0) to server via GSM module. I am sending this data to GSM via UART and sending the data to server using AT command `"AT+HTTPDATA"` and later doing `HTTPPOST`. The problem that I am facing now is, I am able to send the data only till first null character is encountered.

For ex:
In the above string `"welcome\0  my name\0 is"`
I am able to send only till `"welcome"`, but nothing after that.

the sample code is given here:

```c
sent_bytes = uart_write_bytes(UART_NUM_1, dummy_data, size_of_data); /*data that I am sending 
                                                                      with '\0' in between*/
sent_bytes = uart_write_bytes(UART_NUM_1, "\x1A", 2);       //ctrl+z for httpdata to terminate
```

I have tried different ways of sending it, but no luck till now.

For example:

```c
                            for(int f=0;f<=500;f++){
                            char_ptr = dummy_data[f];
                            int l=0;
                            if(char_ptr != '\0' && f <= 500){
                                printf("char_ptr is %c\n", char_ptr);
                                temp[f] = char_ptr;
                                sent_bytes = uart_write_bytes(UART_NUM_1, temp, sizeof(temp));
                                printf("temp value inside condition is %s\n", temp);
                                temp[1000] = "";
                                l++;
                                if(l == 500){
                                    printf("500 reached \n");
                                    goto c2;
                                }else{
                                    printf("500 has not reached, going to c1\n");
                                    // goto c1;
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

Still this code doesn't work and I am able to receive only the string till the first null
i.e., till "welcome" in the above case.

So, if anyone knows the solution for this please let me know. Thanks in advance for any leads.

Comment: "In the above string..." That is not a string. That memory content might be 2 strings but any string ends with the first 0 byte. If you want to handle data containing 0 bytes, you should not deal with strings but just use raw char buffers.

Comment: With that code snippet it is not clear what you are actually doing. Please show more complete piece of code. At least all variable definitions should be visible.

Comment: Here `sent_bytes = uart_write_bytes(UART_NUM_1, temp, sizeof(temp));`, `temp` sems to be array of char. But here you use it as array of pointers: `temp[1000] = "";` You should get some compiler warnings for that

Comment: Do make sure that yours is a transmission problem and not a reception problem or a display problem on the receiving side.